# NSNotification getting called multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, contacts

I have the following code in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(addressBookDidChange),
            name: NSNotification.Name.CNContactStoreDidChange,
            object: nil)
```

This is the method it calls

```
@objc func addressBookDidChange(notification: NSNotification){
                self.processContacts()

    }
```

and here is the notification being removed

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.CNContactStoreDidChange)
    }
```

The problem is that when I add a new contact via the method below, addressBookDidChange gets called multiple times after, not just once

```
func addContact(contact:ContactObject) {
        let store = CNContactStore()

        let contactToAdd = CNMutableContact()
        contactToAdd.givenName = contact.firstName
        contactToAdd.familyName = contact.lastName
        contactToAdd.organizationName = contact.company

        for case let contactNumber as PhoneNumberObject in contact.phoneNumbers!{
            let mobileNumber = CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: contactNumber.number)
            contactToAdd.phoneNumbers.append(CNLabeledValue(label: contactNumber.type.getCNLabelValue(), value: mobileNumber))
        }


        if let image = contact.image {
            contactToAdd.imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        }

        let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
        saveRequest.add(contactToAdd, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)

        do {
            try store.execute(saveRequest)
        } catch {
            NSLog("Error adding contact \(contact.firstName) \(contact.lastName) : \(error)")
        }
    }
```

How can I make the notification be just called once for an addition of one contact?

Comment: where is `NotificationCenter.default.post` ?

Comment: I don't believe that I need one since addressBookDidChange is fired off by Apple since I added the CNContactStoreDidChange observer.

Comment: To be sure the callback is not called by anyone else: try to comment `addObserver `, put a breakpoint in `addressBookDidChange`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is not good idea to set notification posting based on delegate and so what should be doing is post notification from delegate checking condition whether change in notification is contact is added.